# ! Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra }

Tags: sectioning, babel, templates, languages

I've made a LaTeX template for my university documents and I cannot make a `\section` becuase I get the title error. Here's my document template (it must be saved as `aqademia.sty`):

```
\ProvidesPackage{aqademia}

\RequirePackage{titling}

% Package options

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
    \DeclareStringOption[CC]       {ltype}
    \DeclareStringOption[by-nc-sa] {lmodifier}
    \DeclareStringOption[4.0]      {lversion}

    \DeclareStringOption[\thetitle]{title}
    \DeclareStringOption[3]{tab}

    \ProcessKeyvalOptions{aqademia}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

% Licence options

\RequirePackage[type={\aqademia@ltype},           % Createve commons
                modifier = {\aqademia@lmodifier}, % Attribution - NonCommercial - ShareAlike
                version  = {\aqademia@lversion}   % 4.0 International
               ]{doclicense}

% Fonts

\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Mono}

% Physical properties and text shaping and placement

\RequirePackage{vmargin}
    \setpapersize{A4}
    \setmarginsrb{2 cm}   % Left margin
                 {1.5 cm} % Top margin
                 {2 cm}   % Text width
                 {1.5 cm} % Text height
                 {1 cm}   % Header height
                 {0.5 cm} % Header separation
                 {0 cm}   % Footer height
                 {1 cm}   % Footer separation
\RequirePackage[bottom,   % Push all footnotes to the bottom of the page
                multiple, % Allow formatting multiple footnotes for a single term
                norule    % Remove the rule above the footnotes
               ]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{\aqademia@title}
    \rhead{\theauthor}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{Chapter~\thechapter:\\}{0pt}{}[]
    \titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\S\thesection:~}{0pt}{}[]
    \titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\S\thesubsection:~}{0pt}{}[]
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\large}{\S\thesubsubsection:~}{0pt}{}[]
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks = true,
                linkcolor  = black,
                filecolor  = black,
                urlcolor   = darkgray
               }
\RequirePackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{url}

% Colour and graphics settings

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{listing-background} {HTML} {f7f7f7}
    \definecolor{listing-numbers}    {HTML} {8e8e8e}
    \definecolor{listing-text-color} {HTML} {2c2c2c}
    \definecolor{listing-keyword}    {HTML} {6a2398}
    \definecolor{listing-keyword-2}  {HTML} {1284CA} % additional keywords
    \definecolor{listing-keyword-3}  {HTML} {9137CB} % additional keywords
    \definecolor{listing-identifier} {HTML} {2467be}
    \definecolor{listing-string}     {HTML} {568a34}
    \definecolor{listing-comment}    {HTML} {8e8e8e}

% Tables

\RequirePackage{array}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

% Listings

\RequirePackage{listings}
    \lstdefinestyle{aqademia-listings}{basicstyle = \color{listing-text-color}\linespread{1.0}\small\ttfamily{},
                             backgroundcolor  = \color{listing-background},
                             numbers          = left,
                             breaklines       = true,
                             breakindent      = 0pt,
                             frame            = single,
                             xleftmargin      = 0cm,
                             framexleftmargin = 0.08cm,
                             tabsize          = \aqademia@tab,
                             numberstyle      = \color{listing-numbers},
                             keywordstyle     = {\color{listing-keyword}\bfseries},
                             keywordstyle     = {[2]\color{listing-keyword-2}\bfseries},
                             keywordstyle     = {[3]\color{listing-keyword-3}\bfseries\itshape},
                             sensitive        = true,
                             identifierstyle  = \color{listing-identifier},
                             commentstyle     = \color{listing-comment},
                             stringstyle      = \color{listing-string},
                             showstringspaces = false,
                             escapeinside     = {/*@}{@*/}, % Allow LaTeX inside these special comments
                             literate         =
                                 {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'\i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
                                 {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1  {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
                                 {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\'e}}1 {ì}{{\`\i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
                                 {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1  {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
                                 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"\i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
                                 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1  {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
                                 {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^\i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
                                 {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1  {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
                                 {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1  {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
                                 {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
                                 {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
                                 {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
                                 {…}{{\ldots}}1 {≥}{{>=}}1 {≤}{{<=}}1 {„}{{\glqq}}1 {“}{{\grqq}}1
                                 {”}{{''}}1
                            }
    \lstset{escapechar=@,style=aqademia-listings}

% Standalone command definitions and redefinitions
%  \aqappendices -> Start appendix format for the rest of the document
%   \aqtitle -> Render the title page
%   \code -> Print text in monospaced font its size scaled down to the regular font size

\newcommand{\aqchap}[1]{%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
                {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{#1\thechapter:\\}{0pt}{}[]
}

\newcommand{\aqsec}[1]{%
    \titleformat{\section}[block]
                {\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{#1\thesection:~}{0pt}{}[]
}

\newcommand{\aqssec}[1]{%
    \titleformat{\subsection}[block]
                {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{#1\thesubsection:~}{0pt}{}[]
}

\newcommand{\aqsssec}[1]{%
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
                {\normalfont\bfseries\large}{#1\thesubsubsection:~}{0pt}{}[]
}

\newcommand{\aqapp}[1]{%
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}
                 {\MakeUppercase{\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}
                     {\MakeUppercase{\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}
                     {\MakeUppercase{\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
    \aqchap{#1}
}

\newcommand{\aqtitlepage}[4][]{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{titlepage.png}\\[0.5cm]

            \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}
                {\textsc{\Huge{#2}}\\}

            \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}
                {\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm}\\[0.3 cm]}
                {\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm}\\}
            {\huge\bfseries\thetitle\ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{}{~---~#3\\}}
            \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm}\\[1 cm]

            \vfill

            \Large{\textbf{\theauthor}}
            \ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{}
                {\\[0.1cm]\large{\url{#4}}}\\[0.5 cm]
            \large{\thedate}\\[1.5 cm]
        \end{center}

        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nolicense}}
            {}
            {\doclicenseThis}
    \end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{%
    \begingroup\fontsize{9pt}{12pt}\selectfont\texttt{#1}\endgroup
}
```

And here's the document preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

% Language and input encoding

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Document settings

\usepackage{titling}
    \author{Atanasio José Rubio Gil}
    \title{Algorítmica}
    \date{\today}

\usepackage[title=\thetitle]{aqademia}

\aqchap{Tema~}
\aqssec{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Document composition

\begin{document}

\aqtitlepage{Grado en Ingeniería Informática}
            {Teoría}
            {https://github.com/Groctel/ugr-informatica}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{La eficiencia de los algoritmos}

\section{El concepto de algoritmo}

Un algoritmo\footnote{La palabra \textit{algoritmo} proviene del nombre del matemático persa del siglo IX Abd Allah Muhhamad ibn Musa \textbf{al-Khwarizmi}.} es una \textit{secuencia finita ordenada de pasos exentos de ambigüedad tal que, al llevarse a cabo con fidelidad, dará como resultado la tarea para la que se ha diseñado}.
De esta definición podemos extraer algunos términos clave: % ...

\end{document}
```

The error is thrown when `xelatex` tries to parse `\section` and I get this output:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 25.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 7451) in paragraph at lines 29--29
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Esta obra está bajo una licencia [][]Creative Commons «  Recon
ocimiento-
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def) [1]
(./ALG - Teoría.toc) [1]
Capítulo 1.
! Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.35 \section{El concepto de algoritmo}

? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg~ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.35 \section{El concepto de algoritmo}

? 
[2] (./ALG - Teoría.aux) )
Output written on ALG - Teoría.pdf (3 pages).
Transcript written on ALG - Teoría.log.
```

What am I doing wrong in my template or my preamble? I didn't have any problems building the demo file at the template's repo. Could it be a `babel` error?

Comment: probably unrelated but if you are using xelatex do not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (there will be a warning in the log)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It didn't solve the error, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: I tried your example but it uses files not in texlive I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`aqademia.sty' not found.`

Comment: You need to download the template file and put it next to the document you're building @DavidCarlisle

Comment: No sorry I don't wish to do that, and also your question is archived here forever and will not be understandable if that link changes, please make the example in the question self contained.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am unable to reproduce the error if I copy the whole template on the document as a preamble, so that's futile effort. I've uploaded the whole template but it needs to be saved as a different file.

Comment: you could add the style here in a new codeblock  (ah you just did that as I was writing, thanks:-)

Comment: If you're maintaining the package, please avoid `vmargin`: it's buggy and incompatible with several packages, notably Ti*k*Z in some of its (important) features.

Comment: What should I use instead of `vmargin`? @egreg

Comment: @Groctel Use `geometry`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/how-to-use-non-breaking-space-with-usepackagespanishbabel . The solution is the same: `\usepackage[spanish,es-notilde]{babel}`. See also http://www.texnia.com/spanishopt.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reasonable test file showing the same error is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

% Language and input encoding

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Document settings

% section related lines from local package
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\S\thesection:~}{0pt}{}[]

% Document composition

\begin{document}


\section{El concepto de algoritmo}

z

\end{document}
```

The `~` in the heading apparently conflicts with babel spanish use of `~` replacing it by a normal space there makes the error go

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\S\thesection: }{0pt}{}[]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Substituting it works.