# Babel(spanish)/chicago bibliography style conflicting

Tags: bibtex, natbib, babel, spanish

I am writing some class notes, and babel (with `spanish` language option) + `natbib` + `chicago` bibliography style are producing some undesirable results: they give me the `Missing \endcsname inserted.` error when I add a volume to a given article I am trying to cite. The class notes are in spanish so I need babel. A minimal working example of my tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{min}
\author{none}
\date{today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
cite the citation \citep{efron1979}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

and my biblio.bib file:

```
@article{efron1979,
 author={Bradley Efron},
 title={Bootstrap Methods: Another Look at the Jackknife},
 journal={The Annals of Statistics},
 year=1979,
 number=1,
 pages={1-26},
 volume={7}
}
```

If I remove the volume from the cited work in the `.bib` file, for some reason, the code works. But these is a very annoying work around: I still get warnings from BibTex, saying that I have a missing volume. What is the proper solution to this?

Comment: I can reproduce the error you've encountered. Until a longer-term fix is found, can you switch to a different bibliography style?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use non-breaking space (~) with \usepackage\[spanish\]{babel}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/how-to-use-non-breaking-space-with-usepackagespanishbabel)

Comment: An alternative would be to use the `biblatex-chicago` package to print your bibliography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you use utf8 encoding (notice that this is the default since a while; you do not need to explicitly load `inputenc` here, [although you probably do need the `fontenc` to set T1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc)), probably you will input ñ as `ñ` and not as `~n` --- one possibility is to disable the shorthands altogether, as in:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % this IS needed
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}


\title{min}
\author{none}
\date{today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
cite the citation \citep{efron1979}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

which works. If you have Spanish shorthands in the real bib file, though, that will be more complex --- but in BiBTeX file I advocate for plain TeX syntax everywhere, so you have no surprises...

Disabling the `babel` shorthands when using `spanish` will prevent also several other glitches with, for example, TikZ and company.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thanks a lot!